# Problems with DoctrineFixturesBundle upgrading from Symfony 5.1 to 5.2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, composer-php, symfony5

I'm upgrading my Symfony 4.4 project to Symfony 5.4 (the current LTS version). I've tried modifying `composer.json`, forcing directly to the 5.4 release, but I've found lots of dependency problems, so I "solved" this migrating slowly: I moved to 5.0, then to 5.1, and now I'm trying to migrate from 5.1 to 5.2, but I have dependency problems and I don't know how to fix them.

The problem:

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.4.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/persistence[1.3.5] | install one of doctrine/persistence[1.3.7, 1.3.8, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.3.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/persistence[1.3.7] | install one of doctrine/persistence[2.2.1, ..., 2.3.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/common[v2.11.0], doctrine/persistence[2.2.3] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/common[v2.11.0], doctrine/persistence[2.2.2] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/common[v2.11.0], doctrine/persistence[2.2.1] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: install doctrine/common v2.11.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/persistence[1.3.8] | install one of doctrine/persistence[2.2.4, 2.3.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/persistence[2.2.4] | install one of doctrine/common[2.13.1, 2.13.3] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/common[2.13.3] | install doctrine/persistence[2.3.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/common[2.13.1] | install doctrine/persistence[2.3.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/persistence 2.3.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/orm[2.7.5], doctrine/persistence[2.2.4] | install one of doctrine/common[2.13.2, 2.13.3] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/persistence[1.3.6] | install doctrine/persistence[2.2.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/persistence[1.2.0], doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle[3.4.0] | install one of doctrine/persistence[1.3.7, 1.3.8, 2.2.0, ..., 2.3.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/persistence 2.2.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/orm[2.7.5], doctrine/persistence[2.2.2] | install one of doctrine/common[2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/orm[2.7.5], doctrine/persistence[2.2.1] | install one of doctrine/persistence[1.3.8], doctrine/common[2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/orm[2.7.5], doctrine/persistence[2.2.0] | install one of doctrine/persistence[1.3.8], doctrine/common[2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/orm[2.7.5], doctrine/persistence[2.1.1] | install one of doctrine/persistence[1.3.8], doctrine/common[2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/orm[2.7.5], doctrine/persistence[2.1.0] | install one of doctrine/persistence[1.1.1, 1.3.5, 1.3.7, 1.3.8], doctrine/common[2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/orm[2.7.5] | install one of doctrine/persistence[v1.1.0, ..., 1.3.8, 2.1.0, ..., 2.3.0], doctrine/common[2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/common[2.12.0], doctrine/persistence[2.3.0] | install one of doctrine/persistence[v1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/common[2.12.0], doctrine/persistence[2.0.0] | install one of doctrine/persistence[v1.1.0, ..., 1.3.8] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/orm[2.7.4] | install one of doctrine/persistence[v1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.3.8, 2.2.4, 2.3.0], doctrine/common[2.13.1, 2.13.3] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/common[2.12.0], doctrine/persistence[2.1.0] | install one of doctrine/persistence[v1.1.0, ..., 1.3.8] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/common[2.12.0], doctrine/persistence[2.0.1] | install one of doctrine/persistence[v1.1.0, ..., 1.3.8] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/common[v2.11.0], doctrine/persistence[2.2.2] | install one of doctrine/persistence[v1.1.0, ..., 1.3.8] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of symfony/doctrine-bridge[v5.2.10], doctrine/persistence[1.3.4] | install one of doctrine/persistence[2.1.1, ..., 2.3.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/persistence[v1.1.0], doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle[3.4.0] | install one of doctrine/persistence[1.3.7, 1.3.8, 2.1.1, ..., 2.3.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/persistence 2.1.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of symfony/doctrine-bridge[v5.2.10], doctrine/persistence[1.3.6] | install one of doctrine/persistence[2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.3.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/common[2.12.0], doctrine/persistence[2.2.4] | install one of doctrine/persistence[v1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires doctrine/common ^2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.1.3, ..., 2.13.3].
    - Root composer.json requires doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle ^3.4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle[3.4.0, 3.4.1].
    - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.4.0 requires doctrine/persistence ^1.3.7|^2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/persistence[1.3.7, 1.3.8, 2.0.0, ..., 2.3.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/common[v2.11.0], doctrine/persistence[2.1.0] | install one of doctrine/persistence[v1.1.0, ..., 1.3.8] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/common[v2.11.0], doctrine/persistence[2.0.1] | install one of doctrine/persistence[v1.1.0, ..., 1.3.8] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of doctrine/common[v2.11.0], doctrine/persistence[2.0.0] | install one of doctrine/persistence[v1.1.0, ..., 1.3.8] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/persistence[1.1.1] | install one of doctrine/persistence[1.3.7, 2.1.1, ..., 2.2.3] (conflict analysis result)
```

I suppose than the problem is with the package `doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle`, but I'm unsure, because I find it very hard to interpret the error message. Is this the offending package? If so, is there any way to upgrade it, or should I remove it, upgrade the application and then install it again?

I need the package because I use it to populate the test database when running tests, but maybe there is any newer package for this job?

And here is my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "^3.0",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.4",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/common": "^2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^2.6",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
        "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "^2.0",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.13",
        "ramsey/uuid-doctrine": "^1.6",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.4",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.39",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/intl": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.5",
        "symfony/polyfill-uuid": "^1.15",
        "symfony/process": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/translation": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/validator": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.2.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.13"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "dama/doctrine-test-bundle": "^6.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.15",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.2",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "5.2.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.2.*"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know I this can be a help, but this application started as an Symfony 3.4 app, a couple years ago I upgraded to Symfony 4.4, and now I'm working in moving to 5.4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you require `doctrine/common` in v2. This depends on `doctrine/persistence` in v1. Updating all your packages to Symfony 5.2 will also update `symfony/doctrine-bridge` to 5.2 - and this requires `doctrine/persistence` in v2.

---

Updating `doctrine/common` to v3 in your `composer.json` could help to resolve the problem. Also, since you are using `symfony/flex` already, you can remove all explicit version constraints on the Symfony packages - it's sufficient to define the Symfony version further down in the `extra` section as you already did. This makes it way easier to update all Symfony packages, as you only need to change this one line

Comment: Thank you! It nearly worked. Apart from upgrading `doctrine/common` to v3 I had to upgrade `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` and `stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle`. Thank you very much! :)